# Docker: how to update variables inside the container?

Tags: linux, docker

Suppose we have a docker with an Apache container.
I would like to make dynamic the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

I would like to update the path of a site with a variable that I can insert through docker compose

How can I do it ?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myEmail 
    ServerName myCustomHostname
    DocumentRoot /var/myCustomPath 
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html 
    <Directory /var/myCustomPath> 
         Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI 
         AllowOverride None 
         Order allow,deny 
         allow from all 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried to create a docker file of this type:

```
FROM newdeveloper/apache-php
ARG SERVERNAME
ARG FOLDER
ENV SERVERNAME=${SERVERNAME}
ENV FOLDER=${FOLDER}
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install -y python nano
RUN a2enmod cgi
EXPOSE 80
RUN echo "<VirtualHost *:80> \n\
    ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com \n\
    ServerName ${SERVERNAME} \n\
    DocumentRoot ${FOLDER}/html \n\
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html \n\
    #AddHandler cgi-script .py \n\
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ ${FOLDER}/cgi-bin/ \n\
    <Directory ${FOLDER}/html/> \n\
         Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI \n\
         AllowOverride None \n\
         Order allow,deny \n\
         allow from all \n\
    </Directory> \n\
</VirtualHost>" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN echo "ServerName ${servername}"
```

Is this the right way ?
I've done a lot of tests but I can't understand if I'm wrong...
In practice I would like those fields to become variables to be edited with dockercompose for example with the enviroment instruction

UPDATE 1:

This is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  myContainer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - FOLDER=/var/www/html/website
      - SERVERNAME=mydomain.domain.org
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=mydomain.domain.org
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
    expose:
      - 80
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "/myPath/myWebsite:/var/www/html/website"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

And this is the error when I execute docker-compose -f mydocker.yml up :

```
Output of config test was:
   ...fail!
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
AH00526: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
ServerName takes one argument, The hostname and port of the server
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

It seems that the variables are not interpreted by the environment section

Comment: That looks like a reasonable approach. Does it work?

Comment: After running a2enmod cgi according to the docker build you need to restart the apache service running `service apache2 restart`. Did you try to include that within the dockerfile?

Comment: @DanielMarques I have updated the question with the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
environment:
  - FOLDER=/var/www/html/website
  - SERVERNAME=mydomain.domain.org
  - VIRTUAL_HOST=mydomain.domain.org
  - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
```

is wrong. Environment is passed to when *running container* not when *building* the image. Pass them to the build stage.

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  args:
    - FOLDER=/var/www/html/website
    - SERVERNAME=mydomain.domain.org
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=mydomain.domain.org
    - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
```

> Is this the right way ?

"right" is subjective. For me the dockerfile needs to be optimized. Doing so many separate `RUN` will result in bloated image - the installation should be a single `RUN` command preferably with a cleanup. Doing `ARG` and `ENV` before installing things is pointless - do them right before you need them. And I think I would create a separate file with the template and use `envsubst` to substitute environment variables - keeping the file in dockerfile with those `\n\` would be fore me more pain then `COPY + RUN envsubst > file`.